# Syntax Error in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This one gives me a syntax error at `@question`

What is wrong here?

```
@{
    string question = "Really delete?";

<link href="~/Content/sweetalert/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Content/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".delete").on("click", function (e) {
            swal({
                text: @question,
                title: "Delete Confirm",
                //some other stuff...

}
```

Comment: Your missing a closing `}` after `string question = "..";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `text: @question`, should be wrapped in `''` like so

`text: '@question'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `question` this way:
`title: "@question"`

Code:

```
@{
    string question = "Really delete?";
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Content/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".delete").on("click", function(e) {
                swal({
                    title: "@question",
                    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

Comment: Actually it does. I guess the Razor syntax "breaks the Jquery" script. So i guess i will have to use hidden fields and read them from Jquery

Comment: @Chocol8 Check my answer.